# How to make good regexp?

Tags: regex

I need one Regular Expression for all these examples:

```
<319/319hp ***....... 2377860/7094952 87/88mv 2019c 112s 52g 5m> Jadlodajnia [ Wyjscie ] 4
<319/319hp .......... 2377860/7094952 87/88mv 2019c 112s 52g 5m> Ulica Glowna [ E Jadlodajnia W ] 7
<319/319hp ******.... 2377860/7094952 86/88mv 2019c 112s 52g 5m> Ulica Glowna [ E Sklep W ] 7
<319/319hp ********** 2377860/7094952 86/88mv 2019c 112s 52g 5m> Ulica Glowna [ E Sklep W ] 7
```

In all these examples, I would liek to get the `2377860` value but I don't have any idea how to make it.

Comment: Are you going to us the regex in a programming language? In that case, there is probably an easier solution (like splitting on spaces and using the third element). Even if not: please let us know which environment you are using this in. And your own attempt.

Comment: Thanks for edit Ian Kenny, i don't knew how to make good note here.

Comment: @m.buettner , i need this in pseudo-programming language what work in [TinyFugue](http://tinyfugue.sourceforge.net/).
Documentacion tells:
"TF implements regular expressions with the package PCRE 2.08, Copyright (c) 1997-1999 University of Cambridge."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following (Since you use a PCRE engine, it should work):

```
(?<=[.*] )\d+(?=/)
```

It will match the number only.

[Online demo here.](http://regexr.com?35egg)

If your language didn't support look-behind (but it does), you'd have to use:

```
[.*] (\d+)(?=/)
```

And work with the group one (`$1`).

[Demo here.](http://regexr.com?35egj)

Comment: Ah ok, so sorry. I first time used stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like:

```
[*.] (\d+)\/\d+
```

Matches a period or asterisk, a space, then one or more numbers, a forward slash, and one or more numbers again.  The first capture group is what you're after.

You could of course make this shorter or longer depending on how *picky* you want to be, but I usually err on the side of caution.

[Example](http://www.rubular.com/r/OpMUVUky4W)

Comment: You don't need to escape a dot in a character class.

Comment: @HamZa - Yup good call.

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like

```
" (\d{7})/"
```

a space followed by 7 digits and then a /